# ScrollTop not working on update to jQuery 1.11.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrolltop

My website used to use `jQuery 1.3.2`, now I got courage and time to update it to `jQuery 1.11.1` but still I have some problems.
The function bellow used to work but not anymore.
Anyone could help with it?

In scroll down when -user or admin- write a message.

I have added the `jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js` file also already.

The scroll did not run at all. It is halted on top.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="'+PATH_xxx+'js/jquery.min.1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="'+PATH_xxx+'js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="'+PATH_xxx+'js/jquery-ui-11.js"></script>

function ajax_message() {
  $.post(BASE_URL+'chat/ajax_message', {}, function(result){
    $("#mydiv").empty().append(result);
    var count_p = $("#mydiv p").length
    if ($('#roll-auto').attr('checked')) {
      $("#mydiv").attr('scrollTop', count_p * 1500)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Try changing `$("#mydiv").attr('scrollTop', (count_p*1500))` to `$("#mydiv").scrollTop(count_p*1500);`

Comment: it worked perfectly @spaniol6 thanks.

Comment: great! I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery 1.11.1 scrollTop isn't an attribute instead it's used as a function $().scrollTop(positionOnPageToMoveTo);

So just change:

```
$("#mydiv").attr('scrollTop', (count_p*1500))
```

To:

```
$("#mydiv").scrollTop(count_p*1500);
```